# Why is date string changed to day before?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have a Postgres database. In a table I have a column of type „date“.

I try to insert into this db with node express

```
Let myDate = "2022-03-03";
DB.query("INSERT INTO mytable (mydate) VALUES ($1)", [myDate]);
```

But the date in the database is then "2022-03-02". Looks like node is doing some kind of date to datetime conversion and then depending on the timezone reconvert it (because my timezone is 1h behind UTC)

So who can explain what is going on and how to handle this correct?

Comment: Try `let myDate = "2022-03-03Z";`

Comment: What column type is `mydate`?

Comment: JavaScript has no date only data type so times and time zone conversions are always in the mix

Comment: I know, but i give a string to the prepared statement and it makes no sense to convert it to a date because the database is converting it back to a string

Comment: Check your logfiles, also the ones in the PostgreSQL database, to get the entire INSERT statement and it's content for "mydate". The database won't convert a date to a string, a date is just a date. Unless you store a date as a varchar or text, but then you're in trouble anyway.